# determinant calculation of matrix with $a_{i,j}=\cos(x_i+y_j)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, determinant

let $$x_{1},x_{2}...x_{n},y_{1},y_{2},...y_{n}\in \mathbb{R}  
$$

let: $$A = (\cos(x_{i}+y_{j}))_{n \times n}$$

How can I calculate the determinant of this general matrix?
So far I tried ranking the matrix and used $ \cos(x+y) = \cos(x)\cdot \cos(y) + \sin(y)\cdot \sin(x) $  but this haven't yielded any meaningful result.

Comment: Take care : the RHS of your formula for $\cos(x+y)$ isn't exact.

Comment: ...Indeed: $\cos(x+y) = \cos(x)\cdot \cos(y) \color{red}{-} \sin(y)\cdot \sin(x)$